# Single cell selection NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

There are a few google results for this question but they are ancient and didn't really help. So I'm asking again for modern uses, how can I set up selection for a single row and column. Like the Numbers app. So the row/column its self is not highlighted but the focus ring is drawn for the row, column that was selected.

I'm open to Cell based or View based implementation. I have tried doing things inside the

`- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification`
but haven't been able to get things working or looking nice.

Has anyone done this, is there a better view architecture for this?

Comment: I too have been trying to find an answer to this!